# Spacing between UITableViews like Settings Application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm new to iOS dev and I want to have spacing between certain cells like the official settings app has.

Is there a way to do this in one TableView or do I have to insert more of them?

If I have more TableViews the screen is not fully scrollable and maybe not all of them are able to show.

Comment: Share a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: using grouped tableview and separate by section should be spaced like settings app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve a `TableView` that looks like the one in the settings you have to set the `Style` of your `TableView` to `Grouped` and use `Sections` for separating/grouping a certain set of `TableViewCells`.

[image: Set TableView Style to "Grouped"]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myNumberOfRows
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myNumberOfSections
}
```

For more info about `numberOfSections` have a look at the  [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) delegate.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

- If you are using `static` table view: Create Empty cell as a spacing
- If you are using `normal (dynamic)` table view:

  - Create empty cell as a Spacing
  - Emply Space is a Header view and remember to set Table style is `Group`

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to have gaps between sections, u can simply use heightForFooterInSection method of UITableView. This will create gaps between every section. If u desire to have custom views(as in custom color or even images of your choice) you can use viewForFooterInSection method and return the view desired made programmatically or xib created(in case u create a xib u will need to registerNib so that the UIViewController indentifies the xib). You can use every single UI element whos superclass is UIView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default separators between sections make your tableView grouped.  To customize these headers implement these two methods of UITableViewDelegate and change the values as needed.  For instance the settings app as labels on some section breaks instead of empty views:

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return UIView()
        }
    }
```